# How to set content of panel to 100% of the panel body

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am sure this was asked before I just cant mange to find it.

Using a bootstrap panel that is 100% the height of a window, I want the content of the panel .mybox to stretch 100%

```
<body>
<div class="content">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Map</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="mybox"> </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

```
  html, body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
  }
  .content {
      height: 100%;
  }
   .panel {
      height: 100%;
  }
  .panel-body {
      height: 100%;
  }
  .mybox {
      background-color: black;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
  }
```

But the result is that mybox overflows the border of the panel: see this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/rDycxKTFJ8HF2efNhYFl

[image]

I tried playing with the panel padding/margin but setting the bottom to 0 or -5 but dont know how to get the black box to stay inside the panel at 100%, also tried setting the overflow to hidden.

Is there something obvious that I am missing here?

Comment: have you tried to add `<div class="panel-footer">`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set the panel-body bottom padding to the panel-heading 40px + padding size 15px: `padding-bottom: 55px;`

http://plnkr.co/edit/n6ihcucqCkP9dcAKTtu9?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

That must be because of padding. if you give height as `100%` then the actual height of the element will be `100% + padding`. So, remove padding or use `position: absolute` and give `top: 0px; bottom: 0px` which stretches the element to the parent container if the parent container has `position: relative/position:absolute`.

Answer (score 0):

Update your .mybox css with this one:

```
.mybox {
          background-color: black;
          height: calc(100% - 40px);
          width: 100%;
}
```